# Android studio not importing java headers automatically

Tags: java, android

```
package com.origin.aritroghosh.originhome;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter; //error cannot resolve symbol 'BaseAdapter'
/**
 * Created by aritroghosh on 03/09/14.
 */
public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
}
```

Android studio not importing java header files and also showing errors while added manually

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Settings`->`Editor`->`AutoImports`->And click on optimize imports on the fly and also add unambigous imports on the fly